# How can I efficiently find the kth shortest interval containing a specific value m using a self-balancing tree?

Tags: tree

I have a problem where I need to find the kth shortest interval that contains a value m. Example: I have intervals [1,3], [1,5] and want the 2th shortest interval that contains the value m=2. Then the result would be [1,3].

I have built a self balancing tree which stores the intervals based on the starting value of the range. If the starting values are the same then if the ending value is bigger then the node is also bigger. Also each node has stores the maximum upper value among all the intervals from this node down. How should I approach finding kth shortest interval with value m efficiently using this tree?